# How to deal with missing arguement error

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function like the one below:

```
if(!isGeneric("setSoilType")){
  setGeneric("setSoilType", function(soil) {standardGeneric("setSoilType")});
}
setMethod("setSoilType", signature(soil = "numeric"),
function(soil){
  K <- 200 * soil
  K
})
```

However anytime I type `setSoilType()`, I get the following error message and have to debug:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘setSoilType1’ for signature ‘"missing"’"

How can I deal with this so that when I type `setSoilType()` I will not get that error message but will get something like "argument missing"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isGeneric("setSoilType")){
  setGeneric("setSoilType", function(soil) {standardGeneric("setSoilType")});
}
setMethod("setSoilType", signature("soil"),
function(soil){
  K <- 200 * soil
  K
})
```

which I'm basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395772/optional-arguments-in-s4-generics).

You make need to re-write it a little more to be more like the example I linked.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define a nullary overload which prints the error:

```
setMethod('setSoilType',signature(),function() stop('argument missing.',call.=F));
setSoilType();
## Error: argument missing.
```